# Get previously created background color (user input) after restart of Android app

Tags: android, css, xml, eclipse

hey i want to change my background color of my app as it changes on every button click but it resets to default whenever i restart it so how can i change it to remain same.

```
    final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        private int  stateChanged=1;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(stateChanged==1) {
                txt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pk);
            } else if(stateChanged==2) {
                txt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jk);
            } else if(stateChanged==3) {
                txt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sk);
            } else{
                txt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style);
            }
              stateChanged++;
            if(stateChanged==5){
                stateChanged=1;
            }
        }
    });
```

style is my default background and how can i change my status bar color along with background ??

Working on API-17